# Small, minimalistic and fast XML library for Java?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

Sometimes I need to parse XML file - and only parse, and I don't want to do this manually via `String.indexOf`. So my need would be to use possibly smallest and fast XML parsing library. Unfortunatelly, I don't know anything similar to **GSON** (180kb).

I've imported **dom4j**, but after that I've got exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jaxen/JaxenException

So I've added **jaxen** dependency (maven), and this is very shocking experience: about 7MB dependencies added, the biggest from them *xercesImpl* and *icu4j*.

Another guess is **Jericho**, but this is mostly designed for parsing bad-formed HTML, and it's over 2MB - surely there could be something smaller available.

So, could you please recommend me some good library? The minimal code size is the most important thing here. At best it should about the size of **GSON**.

Comment: XML DOM and SAX parsers have been included in the standard Java library since at least Java 1.4. Why not just use that? Then you don't need any third-party library at all.

Comment: @artbristol: because he may be shipping to cellphones or thousands of desktop? *(I'm not saying OP is actually doing that: all I'm saying is that these are not unreasonable requirements)*

Comment: Small size makes sending app to remote server quicker, and when for example the war has > 2MB I can send it to server admin via mail, not a good idea for > 10MB ... Another thing is simplicity of usage, many XML's are used for simply wrapping data structures, they have no DTS's and namespaces, and I would like them to be as simple to map as with GSON

Comment: If you're emailing .war files to a server admin for deployment, you have bigger problems than the size of the XML library you're using. Your time would probably be better spent solving them.

Comment: Look into vtd-xml, or vtd-xml light, whose jar file is under 100k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at NanoXML - [download site](http://nanoxml.sourceforge.net/orig/)

It is a very small DOM-based  parser library, I've used it in the past and it worked well.  It is not necessarily efficient but it is tiny.

Answer (score 2):

JAXB. It is part of the standard Java platform so you don't need any extra libraries. It will bind XML directly to Java classes.

Comment: @lechlukasz - Java SE 6 is now over 5 years old and will reach support EOL in November 2012 (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html).  So JDK 1.6 is a reasonable baseline to expect.

Comment: Maybe in theory, but in practic java 1.4 is still widely used

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with the `javax.xml.parsers` in the Java Standard Libary?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html