# Java Pattern regex to extract between tags

Tags: java, regex, xml, pattern-matching

I am trying to design my custom XML Reader for RSS Feeds. Below is my JAVA Code in testing:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<(item)(.*?)>((.*))</\\1>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("<item value=\"key\" atr='none'><title val=\"has value\">Good</title><link>www</link></item>"
+ "<item value=\"key\" atr='none'><title val=\"has value\">Bad</title><link>http</link></item>"
+ "<item value=\"key\" atr='none'><title val=\"has value\">Neutral</title><link>ftp</link></item>");

while (matcher.find()) {
for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("\n" + i + ":" + matcher.group(i));
}}
```

Here is the output:

```
0:<item value="key" atr='none'><title val="has value">Good</title><link>www</link></item><item value="key" atr='none'><title val="has value">Bad</title><link>http</link></item><item value="key" atr='none'><title val="has value">Neutral</title><link>ftp</link></item>

1:item

2: value="key" atr='none'

3:<title val="has value">Good</title><link>www</link></item><item value="key" atr='none'><title val="has value">Bad</title><link>http</link></item><item value="key" atr='none'><title val="has value">Neutral</title><link>ftp</link>
```

Desired Output:

```
<title val="has value">Good</title><link>www</link>
<title val="has value">Bad</title><link>http</link>
<title val="has value">Neutral</title><link>ftp</link>
```

Basically I want loop should run as much time as much the number of item tag is present in Source String. Currently the 3rd group in regex is extracting the String till the last end tag matching 1st group, which should not be the case. 3rd group should contain the string till the matching the respective end tag of 1st group.

EDIT:
On the recommendation of @11thdimension, I am adding some more information what I need:

1. XML Structure can contain other tags also in ITEM tag, like date, author, etc. The code should retrieve those tags also with title & link tags.
2. Hierarchy of tags is not fixed. They can be any order: title, link, date or link, title, date or date, link, title etc.

Comment: Why don't you use one of the existing XML parsers instead? Regex is not the right tool for the job...

Comment: @Lucero i tried, but they are pretty slow and requires too much overhead. In my knowledge JAVA doesn't has any in build XML parser. We have to rely on external sources. In addition the XML structure could differ depending on source. If that happens then coding for different XML structure with different tag names is not so robust. So I am designing a simple XML Parser according to my needs that can read multiple structures. I am not saying I'm developing best, but it suits me most.

Comment: I think you are mistaken. First XML support has been bundled with Java for a long time now (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430392/small-minimalistic-and-fast-xml-library-for-java). Second XML parsers are completely structure-independent as long as the input is valid XML, much in contrast to your regex-based parser. And third if you want to compare sequential parse performance, don't read the XML into a DOM representation but use a reader instead.

Comment: As for your regex implementation, never ever use `.*` without lazy qualifier in something like this, you will always shoot yourself in the foot. Note that the `.` may not match what you expect it to match unless you add the `DOTALL` flag. But that doesn't change the fundamental flaw when using regex for more than tokenization; it cannot deal with recursion and pairs so it will always fail you at some point when reading structured data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an XML parser as suggested by Lucero.

However if you must use RegEx then you can use following.

```
<title.*?<\/link>
```

Working regex101 link https://regex101.com/r/EWG2Io/2

**Edit**

For the special case where you need everything inside `<item></item>` use following

```
<item.*?>(.*?)<\/item>
```

Working example https://regex101.com/r/Ow1A5F/1

Also here's Java sample

```
public class TestRegex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "<item value=\"key\" atr='none'><date><date><title val=\"has value\">Good</title><link>www</link></item><item value=\"key\" atr='none'><title val=\"has value\">Bad</title><link>http</link><author></author></item><item value=\"key\" atr='none'><title val=\"has value\">Neutral</title><link>ftp</link></item>";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<item.*?>(.*?)<\\/item>");

        Matcher match = pattern.matcher(str);

        while(match.find()) {
            System.out.println(match.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
<date><date><title val="has value">Good</title><link>www</link>
<title val="has value">Bad</title><link>http</link><author></author>
<title val="has value">Neutral</title><link>ftp</link>
```

Comment: Your solution is good, but there are some exceptions. First it will not give the desired result if structure is manipulated, for e.g. <link>ftp</link><title>any title</title>. Second, if there are other tags in  item tags after link tag, it will not grab them. <title>any</title><link>ftp</link><date>12 feb</date>, it will skip date

Comment: It will give the desired result as long as you're interested only in `<title>` and `<link>`, you think it won't then please add the special case in the question

Comment: @ 11thdimension, I have added some more information as per you recommended. ThanksI have added some more information as per you recommended. Thanks